# Errores en herencia de Clases

Tags: c++

verán, tengo problemas al momento de heredar los atributos de una clase, esta al momento de predefinirla no me la reconoce, el objetivo del programa es tener una clase principal llamada Persona, esta clase tendrá dos clases hijas, llamada Estudiante y Trabajador, en este momento solo he estado intentando heredar los atributos para la clase hija Estudiante, pero al momento de pasarle los atributos la edad no me lo reconoce en esta parte `Estudiante::Estudiante(string _nombre, string _ciudad, int edad,string _codigoAlumno, float _notafinal):Persona(_nombre, _ciudad, _edad){` y es justo en `_edad` que este me dice el identificador no esta definido, pero como lo podrán notar en el código que adjuntare a continuación si lo defino, acepto consejos, de ante mano, muchas gracias.

Codigo:

```
/*Crear un programa en C++ que contenga una clase Base llamada Persona, la cual

Deberá tener 2 clases hijas: Estudiante, empleado.
La clase base Persona deberá tener al menos 3 atributos en común a las clases hijas, las
cuales heredarán dichos atributos. Cada clase hija deberá tener 2 atributos únicos.

Cada clase debe tener su propio constructor y un método mostrar.

Pedir datos por teclado.*/

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

//Clase Padre
class Persona{

    private: //Atributos
    string nombre,ciudad;
    int edad;
    public: //Metodos
    Persona(string,string,int); //Constructor
    void mostrarPersona();
};



//Constructor de la clase Persona (Clase Padre)
Persona::Persona(string _nombre,string _ciudad, int _edad){
    nombre=_nombre;
    ciudad=_ciudad;
    edad=_edad;
}

//Clase Hija de la Clase Persona
class Estudiante : public Persona{
    private: //Atributos
    string codigoAlumno;
    float notaFinal;
    public: //Metodos
    Estudiante(string,string,int,string,float); //Constructor de la clase Estudiante
    void mostrarEstudiante(); 
};

//Constructor de la clase Hija
Estudiante::Estudiante(string _nombre, string _ciudad, int edad,string _codigoAlumno, float _notafinal):Persona(_nombre, _ciudad, _edad){
    codigoAlumno=_codigoAlumno;
    notaFinal=_notafinal;
}

void Persona::mostrarPersona(){
    cout<<"Nombre: "<<nombre<<endl;
    cout<<"Ciudad de origen: "<<ciudad<<endl;
    cout<<"Edad de la persona: "<<edad<<endl;
}

void Estudiante::mostrarEstudiante(){
    mostrarPersona();
    cout<<"Codigo Alumno: "<<codigoAlumno<<endl;
    cout<<"Nota Final: "<<notaFinal<<endl;

}

int main(void){

    string nombre11,ciudad11,codigoAlumno11,codigoTrabajador11;
    int edad11,op;
    float notaFinal11;

   /* cout<<"Seleccione la opcion para Estudiante o Trabajador: "<<endl;
    cout<<"Opcion 1= Estudiante, Opcion 2= Trabajador";
    cin>>op;*/
  
    cout<<"Ingrese el nombre del Estudiante ";
    cin>>nombre11;
    cout<<"Ingrese la Edad del Estudiante: ";
    cin>>edad11;
    cout<<"Ingrese la Ciudad de origen: ";
    cin>>ciudad11;
    cout<<"Ingrese el Coidigo del Alumno: ";
    cin>>codigoAlumno11;
    cout<<"Ingrese la nota final del estudiante: ";
    cin>>notaFinal11;
    
    Estudiante estudiante1(nombre11,edad11,ciudad11,codigoAlumno11,notaFinal11);


    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Todos tus problemas se solucionan compilando y entendiendo los errores del compilador, por esta tiene un pase porque eres nuevo y estás aprendiendo. Pero la próxima vez que publiques una pregunta sobre errores de compilación que se solucionan simplemente leyendo, votaré para su cierre.

Answer (score 0):

El compilador da mensajes claros y concisos sobre cuáles son los errores, yo he usado gcc y me avisa de lo siguiente:

> ```
> error: use of undeclared identifier '_edad'; did you mean 'edad'?
> Estudiante::Estudiante(string _nombre, string _ciudad, int edad,string _codigoAlumno, float _notafinal):Persona(_nombre, _ciudad, _edad){
>                                                                                                                                   ^~~~~
> no matching constructor for initialization of 'Estudiante'
> Estudiante estudiante1(nombre11,edad11,ciudad11,codigoAlumno11,notaFinal11);
>            ^           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'std::__cxx11::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') for 2nd argument
> Estudiante::Estudiante(string _nombre, string _ciudad, int edad,string _codigoAlumno, float _notafinal):Persona(_nombre, _ciudad, _edad){
>             ^
> ```

Si en inglés te cuesta entenderlo, traduzco los errores:

> ```
> error: uso de identificador no declarado '_edad'; ¿te referías a 'edad'?
> Estudiante::Estudiante(string _nombre, string _ciudad, int edad,string _codigoAlumno, float _notafinal):Persona(_nombre, _ciudad, _edad){
>                                                                                                                                   ^~~~~
> no se encuentra un constructor para inizializar 'Estudiante'
> Estudiante estudiante1(nombre11,edad11,ciudad11,codigoAlumno11,notaFinal11);
>            ^           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> nota: el constructor candidato no es viable: no se conoce una conversión desde 'int' a 'std::string' para el segundo argumento
> Estudiante::Estudiante(string _nombre, string _ciudad, int edad,string _codigoAlumno, float _notafinal):Persona(_nombre, _ciudad, _edad){
>             ^
> ```

Para empezar, en `//Constructor de la clase Hija` el parámetro se llama `edad` pero tú lo usas como `_edad` al pasarle los parámetros a la clase base.

Para acabar, cuando construyes `estudiante` en `main`, el segundo parámetro debería ser una cadena (la ciudad) pero tú le pasas un entero.

Comment: Entendido, muchas gracias por ello, aun me cuesta trabajo entender los errores del compilador, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.